# Tic Tac Toe bot with minimax not able to find best move

Tags: javascript, algorithm, minimax

I am trying to make a tic tac toe ai with minimax algorithm, following the tutorial by freecodecamp. But the bot is not able to find winning moves. I tried comparing the code to other people's code and I don't find any mistakes.

I checked the move which was returned by the function and it's returning a move with a score of -10 even though a move with score 10 was available.

Please tell me what's wrong with my code.

```
function minimax(gameBoard, player){
    if(checkWin(gameBoard, bot)) return {score: 10};
    if(checkWin(gameBoard, human)) return {score: -10};
    
    var emptyCells = board.filter(e => typeof e === "number");
    
    if(emptyCells.length===0) return {score: 0};
    
    var possibleMoves = [];
    
    for(var i=0;i<emptyCells.length;i++){
        var move = {};
        move.id = gameBoard[emptyCells[i]];
        
        gameBoard[emptyCells[i]] = player;
        
        if(player === bot){
            move.score = minimax(gameBoard, human).score;
        }else{
            move.score = minimax(gameBoard, bot).score;
        }
        
        gameBoard[emptyCells[i]] = move.id;
        possibleMoves.push(move);
        
        var bestMove;
        if(player === bot){
            var bestScore = -100;
            for(var i=0;i<possibleMoves.length;i++){
                if(possibleMoves[i].score>bestScore){
                    bestScore = possibleMoves[i].score;
                    bestMove = i;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            var bestScore = 100;
            for(var i=0;i<possibleMoves.length;i++){
                if(possibleMoves[i].score<bestScore){
                    bestScore = possibleMoves[i].score;
                    bestMove = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return possibleMoves[bestMove];
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging? What were your findings?

Comment: I did try debugging by putting a console.log line to check if the checkWin function is being called and it is. But for some reason {score: 10} is not being returned even though a winning move is possible and the console.log line just before the return statement was executed. In the end a move with score -10 is being returned instead.

Comment: My knowledge of javascript is pretty limited but as a hint your issue is probably due to scoping... which you'd catch by inspection or by stepping through via a debugger.

Comment: @wLui155 What do you mean by a scoping issue? I'm not a professional developer so I don't know many terms like this. Could you explain?

Comment: *"it's returning a move with a score of -10 even though a move with score 10 was available"*: please provide the concrete value of the parameters with which you called `minimax` when this was happening. Is this your actual code?? Because `board` is nowhere defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your function `checkWin` has no mistakes, and that the arguments you pass in the initial call are valid, there are the following two issues in your code:

- In the following statement there is a reference to `board`, which should really be `gameBoard`:

  ```
  var emptyCells = board.filter(e => typeof e === "number");
  ```
- The part of the code that determines `bestMove` (starting with `var bestMove;`) should not be inside the loop. You want to *first* add all the moves to `possibleMoves`, and only *then* iterate those to find the best move. But right now you search for a best move each time you add one move to `possibleMove`. Worse still, you use the *same* loop variable `i` which is already used in the outer loop, which will completely mix up your outer loop.

Fixing these two issues should resolve the problem you described.

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed the typo with board instead of gameBoard. I think fixing these problems should work.

Comment: In fact, the typo would prevent the code from running, unless you have a global variable `board` hanging around somewhere, so that is rather straightforward. The second problem takes a bit more analysis to spot. You write *"should work"*: did you try?

Comment: Yes I had a global variable named board. I tried it and it works. Thanks!